# Is there any way to append an element/value to a tuple?

Tags: swift, tuples

Is there anyway to add a new element to a tuple?

```
var tuple = (v1: 1,v2: 2)

tuple.v3 = 3 // Error
```

> "error: value of tuple type '(v1: Int, v2: Int)' has no member 'v3'"

Comment: No, because a tuple with 2 values is a completely different type than a tuple that has 3 values.

Comment: What you need is an array not a tuple. If you need to name them use a dictionary

Comment: @LeoDabus This was just intellectual curiosity about tuples :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Each tuple with a different number of elements or a different type of elements represents a different type in the `Swift` type system. Hence, once you create a tuple, you cannot append elements to it, because that would change the type of the tuple.

Some really basic examples of tuples and their types:

```
let tupleWithTwoInts = (1,2) //has type (Int,Int)
let tupleWithThreeInts = (1,2,3) //has type (Int,Int,Int)
let tupleWithTwoStrings = ("a","b") //has type (String,String)
let tupleWithIntAndString = (1,"a") //has type (Int,String)
let tupleWithStringAndInt = ("a",1) //has type (String,Int)
```

Even the order of the elements make a difference in the type of a tuple.

```
type(of: tupleWithIntAndString) == type(of: tupleWithStringAndInt) //false
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to support some small number of operations, then you can write a function for it.

For example, extending a 2D vector into 3D:

```
func expand(_ v: (x: Int, y: Int), z: Int) -> (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) {
    return (x: v.x, y: v.y, z: z)
}
```

Comment: `let m = expand((5,2),z: 6)
m.x` will give this error **value of tuple type '(Int, Int, Int)' has no member 'x'**. Though `m.0` works...

Comment: @Honey Because I forgot to put the `x/y/z` labels on the return type of the tuple. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

While there is no extensible way to convert your array to a tuple as stated above, if you arrived at this question because you are making reusable components, and you like the convenience that variadic declarations can provide, you can move your method body into one that takes an array and let your variadic declaration be an alternate wrapper for the same method.

**This**

```
func buttonModels(_ buttonModels: ButtonModel...) {
    self.buttonModels = buttonModels
}
```

**Becomes:**

```
func buttonModels(_ buttonModels: ButtonModel...) {
    self.buttonModels(buttonModels)
}

func buttonModels(_ buttonModels: [ButtonModel]) {
    self.buttonModels = buttonModels
}
```

Answer (score -4):

It seems to me that you are looking to use a dictionary, not a tuple. See the docs: [Tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/tuple-type)

EDIT: As pointed out, tuples can indeed be mutable if you declare them as a var and can be used to hold editable data. My bad!

Comment: `and are immutable` Wrong. Mutable if `var`, immutable if `let`.

Comment: I'll leave it as a hallmark of my shame. If the community deems it deleteworthy, it will be deleted anyway.